# How to do a Count in PL/SQL Query

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have to create a PL/SQL query that will display the vehicle vin number, vehicle type and how many deliveries have currently been made with the vehicle. And if the VIN_NUMBER has a count of 2 or more then it requires inspection. I don't know how to get the count working or where exactly to put it in a PL/SQL query and I also need some guidance on how to do the if and else statements on whether the vehicle requires inspection or not based on the count.

The VIN_NUMBER(will also be used for the count) comes from the DRIVER_DELIVERIES table and the VEHICLE_TYPE comes from the Vehicle Table.

Here's my code so far:

```
DECLARE
  VINNUM   VARCHAR2(20);
  VEH      VARCHAR2(30);
  INSPECTION VARCHAR2(30);
  CNT NUMBER(2);
  BEGIN
  FOR i IN
  (
    SELECT 
        VIN_NUMBER,
        VEHICLE_TYPE,
        INSPECTION,
        COUNT(*) CNT
        INTO
        VINNUM, VEH
    FROM 
        DRIVER_DELIVERIES,
        VEHICLE
    WHERE DRIVER_DELIVERIES.VIN_NUMBER = VEHICLE.VIN_NUMBER 
    GROUP BY 
        VIN_NUMBER,
        VEHICLE_TYPE,
        INSPECTION
  )
  LOOP

    IF i.CNT >= 2 THEN

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('VIN NUMBER : ' ||I.VIN_NUMBER);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('VEHICLE : ' ||I.VEHICLE_TYPE);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DELIVERY COUNT: ' ||I.CNT);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('INSPECTION : ' ||I."Inspection Required");

        if count <2 THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('VIN NUMBER : ' ||I.VIN_NUMBER);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('VEHICLE : ' ||I.VEHICLE_TYPE);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DELIVERY COUNT: ' ||I.CNT);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('INSPECTION : ' ||I."Inspection Not Required");

    END IF ;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Error report -
ORA-06550: line 41, column 7:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "LOOP" when expecting one of the following:

if
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Here's the sample results that I should have:

VIN NUMBER:            1ZA55858541

VEHICLE:                     Cutaway van chassis

DELIVERY COUNT:     2

INSPECTION:              INSPECTION REQUIRED

---

VIN NUMBER:            1ZA35858543

VEHICLE:                     Medium Standard Truck

DELIVERY COUNT:    1

INSPECTION:              INSPECTION NOT REQUIRED

---

VIN NUMBER:         1ZA15851545

VEHICLE:                   Flatbed truck

DELIVERY COUNT:  1

INSPECTION:           INSPECTION NOT REQUIRED

---

VIN NUMBER:         1ZA35868540

VEHICLE:                 Cutaway van chassis

DELIVERY COUNT: 1

INSPECTION:           INSPECTION NOT REQUIRED

Comment: There is really nothing on Google for how to do a count in pl/sql for Oracle?

Comment: I have tried google first but I need to know how to add the Count after VIN_NUMBER, VEHICLE_TYPE because when I try to do it myself I get an error and the tutorials I've used are only one line Select Count ___ statements. I think I have to do another select statement after the first one for this to work right?

Comment: This looks like something you should be able to do in SQL, no PL/SQL procedure should be needed. Whenever a SQL solution is possible, it should be preferred. If you show us the data structure (table or tables storing the input data, with column names and types, as you could get in SQL*Plus with DESCRIBE <table_name>), we can help you with a SQL query. Question though... it may not be enough to find vehicles with 2 or more deliveries. Shouldn't that be 2 or more deliveries SINCE THE LAST INSPECTION? So you must have data about inspections somewhere as well.

Comment: @mathguy, I know you can do it in SQL but I need to be able to do it in a PL/SQL procedure for college, I can do it the other way but I need to learn how to do it this way

Comment: Understood. How about the other questions (especially the last one)?

Comment: @mathguy There's only two more questions after this,:
Q9. Create a PL/SQL query that will display the driver first name and surname that has not yet made a delivery.  
In your query include a print out to determine if the driver requires a delivery job. 
Q10. Create a view to display the customer name, the description of the delivery and how many days the delivery took if the customer received the item on the 15 December 2016. In your query only show the results for the billing id 804 and the code to execute the view.
I wouldn't have any issues with those questions though.

Comment: No... I meant MY questions, not your homework list. Do you need ALL deliveries for a vehicle to be greater or equal to 2, or only deliveries SINCE THE LAST INSPECTION? But since this is homework, not a real life application, perhaps the teacher or textbook didn't even think about that.

Comment: @mathguy I've fixed it now, thanks for the help. I needed the it to just display a certain message if the count was >=2 and a different message if it was less < 2 and it's all working now :)

Comment: Definitely a `do my work`. Same posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36377746/create-a-pl-sql-query

Comment: @J.Chomel it was not a do my work, I have only asked for help. I provided what I've done myself and all I asked for was help on how to fix it and then with the help that I got, I managed to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope below snippet helps. Please incorporate join condition in below snippet.

```
BEGIN
  FOR I IN
  (SELECT VIN_NUMBER,
    VEHICLE_TYPE,
    INSPECTION,
    COUNT(DELIVERY) CNT
  FROM DRIVER_DELIVERIES,
    VEHICLE
  WHERE         <
  JOIN CONDITION> -- Please provide join condition
  GROUP BY VIN_NUMBER,
    VEHICLE_TYPE,
    INSPECTION
  )
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('VIN NUMBER : ' ||I.VIN_NUMBER);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('VEHICLE : ' ||I.VEHICLE_TYPE);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DELIVERY COUNT: ' ||I.CNT);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('INSPECTION : ' ||I.INSPECTION);
  END LOOP;
END;
```